# Bypassing Tesseract preProcessing

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j, graphical-programming

I am running a series of **OCR** on images using **tess4j** as a wrapper for **tesseract** from **JAVA**. The process of ocr is still taking a significant amount of time (even 5 seconds sometimes) and I am trying to speed it up.

I am doing my own preprocessing and binarization of the image and it is not necessary for tesseract to do the otsu binarization.

I have read a tutorial for IOS that allows skipping the graphical processing part , but i can't find anything using tess4j.

The turial here: https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/wiki/Tips-for-Improving-OCR-Results - 
 "... if you've already performed your own pre-processing/thresholding [...] you will probably want to bypass the internal Tesseract thresholding step. "

Does anybody know how I could use **tess4j** (from JAVA) in a way that would skip the otsu binarization?

Comment: any news on that one?

Answer (score 1):

Check [tesseract-ocr parameters](http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-ocr-parameters-in-302-version) list for any settings applicable. But I read that if you send in a binarized image, Tesseract will skip the thresholding on the image ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/tesseract-ocr/Disable$20image$20pre-processing/tesseract-ocr/beouvbCprNU/6xu7hgWgGP8J)).

Comment: I tested with a colorized image and the binarized version and there were no difference in time. 

I am sending the images as PNG, do you know if i should set any attribute in the image to monochrome?

Comment: The [thresholder](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/ccmain/thresholder.cpp) tests image's bit depth / 8 == 0 to determine whether to do it or not. So make sure your image has 1bpp.